# Binding Of Isaac sound problem

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I recently purchased the Wrath of the Lamb expansion and since then there's no in-game music and no sound...

I have just recently formatted my computer and re-installed Windows XP, I don't know if it has something to do with the issue.

Comment: Can you try to verify game files with steam?

Comment: @alperen: Do you get sound in other games or within Windows itself?